# Freeing malloc will not erase char data

Tags: c, string, malloc, concatenation

I made a smaller scenario of my bigger problem. What I try to do is pass a string to a function which will make a new string out of it. However I ran into some problems.

I have defined string as

```
typedef char string[1024];
```

Then I have a function that takes a string and makes a new string which get filled with the old string and a dot char

```
string* add_sth_to_string(char* msg){
    string* newStr=malloc(sizeof(string)); // malloc a newStr
    strcpy(*newStr, msg);            // copying msg to newStr

    char buff[1024];                 // making a buffer
    strcat(buff, ".");               // adding a dot to buffer
    strcat(buff, *newStr);           // adding msg   to buffer
    strcpy(*newStr, buff);           // copying buffer to newStr
    return newStr;
}
```

Then in main I try to use this function 3 times for a new string each time:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    string* newStr;
    newStr=add_sth_to_string("test");
    printf("str: %s\n", *newStr);
    free(newStr);
    // can even printf here
}
```

This is the weird output I get:

```
str: .test
str: .test.test
str: .test.test.test
```

When I would expect to get:

```
str: .test
str: .test
str: .test
```

Anyone who can point out what is happening? Something else I find weird is that I can printf the value of newStr just after I have **freed** it.

Comment: By the way, I don't think that that `typedef` is a good idea. Hiding arrays is even a worst idea than hiding pointers.

Comment: @Matteo as said this is a smaller version of my bigger program. In the real program it's a `typedef struct request` and in there resides `char URN[MAX_PATH]`. Just tryied to make the problem easier to read(which seems to got me downvoted also).

Comment: Uh, sorry, then it's ok; I tend to point out that kind of mistakes because they are quite common between beginners. (By the way, I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `buff` without initializing it. Try:

```
char buff[1024];
buff[0] = 0;
```

> Something else I find weird is that I can printf the value of newStr
>   just after I have freed it.

Accessing memory after freeing it is **undefined behavior**. Typically, for performance reasons, `free` doesn't zero the memory.

That's 2 cases of undefined behavior in the same question + one really weird `typedef`. Keep it up!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
strcat(buff, ".");
```

into

```
strcpy(buff, ".");
```

Or alternativly initialise `buff` when declaring it like so:

```
 char buff[1024] = "";
```

Comment: +1. This is the real problem, because the buffer is unitialized and therefore using `strcat` on it may produce random things.

Comment: Initializing large string buffers is generally a bad idea because it does not just initialize the first byte with a null terminator; it zero-fills the **whole buffer**, which is a waste of time and machine code when you're about to overwrite it anyway. Just writing `buf[0]=0;` on the next like after defining it uninitialized would be better.

Comment: @R. "... it zero-fills the _whole buffer_ ... " is this a somehow standardised (in means of C-standard) behavior?

Comment: @alk: Yes. C does not have partially initialized objects. An initialized object is always fully initialized. 6.7.8: "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration." A useful side-effect is that `{0}` is a universal all-zero initializer for **any type**.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear content of `buf[1024]` each iteration.

---

UPDATE

Because `buf[1024]` will not be zero-ed automatically when allocated on the stack. And you choose `strcat` to concatenate two string, which will find a `\0`-terminate. Thus if `buf` contains some default value, it will introduce obfuscated output.

Use `buf[1024] = "";` to allocate a buffer will correct the output.

Comment: be careful to not put your initializer in a hot loop, it's the equivalent of `memset(buf, 0, 1024);`

Comment: @tristopia any problem with that? What if I put it there? Sorry for my lack of experience and thanks. :)

Comment: The problem with that, is that it looks like a light instruction but is quite costly. I have seen tons of code in which this kind of initializers were used and that had a high impact on the performance of the apps. I had once a case where 1/3 of the CPU time was spent in these initializers.

Comment: @tristopia Thanks for sharing. Forgot `memset` is costly. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string* newStr=malloc(sizeof(string)); // malloc a newStr
strcpy(*newStr, msg);            // copying msg to newStr
```

<strike>This will also crash.  `string` is a pointer so sizeof of it will return 4 or 8, not what you wanted to do.</strike>

Ok, forget about my remark you made a typedef, but I let it here to show you why the typedef is a **bad** idea. At first glance it obfuscated the fact that it was an array and not a pointer, on a 30 line program it's not a probleme, but when you have to maintain a 200 000 lines project (as I do), you will start to hate these kind of things.

Another point, you should avoid to work with fixed sized strings of 1024 bytes. 1024 is not that big (even homecomputer of the 80s had screens bigger than that) and for the majority if strings, which are fairly short, you spoil a lot of memory for nothing.

Comment: I would argue that 99.99% of typedefs are a bad idea.  They typically save 5 or six characters in each declaration, which is very little gain for the obfuscation they impose.

Comment: I wouldn't go that high in the percentage, there are legitimate uses of `typedef`. Creating aliases with semantics of integral types for instance, `HWND` and `time_t` are both integers, but with an attached semantic. What is unforgivable (imho) are typedef's hiding the nature (pointer, array, unction) of the object. Windows' `LPSTR` are examples of that. That's also a reason I don't like references in C++.